# cakephp validation if file is empty required false else check the validation file extension

Tags: php, cakephp

"cakephp validation for if file is empty, required false and file is upload check the validation file extension is doc, pdf"

```
1) in model:-
2) 'pdf' => array( 
    'required'=>array(   
      'allowEmpty' => true,
      ),    
      'rule2'=>array(
        'rule' => array('checkpdf'),
        'message' => 'Please enter valid file.'
      )
    )
3) /***Name : Check file name or extestion*/     
    public function checkpdf($data){  
      $file=$data['pdf'];if(isset($file)){
        if(!empty($file)){
          if($file['type']== 'application/pdf'){ 
            return true; 
            }else{
              return false;
            }
          }else{
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you explain better?

Comment: My question is user upload a file form. check file upload or not, if file is not upload that the not show error message. File is uploaded that the check validation (file extension PDF or DOC)

Comment: @PraveenKumar don't repeat the question in a comment _edit the question_ so that it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function checkpdf($data){
    $file=$data['project_pdf'];
    if(isset($file)){
        if(!empty($file)){ 
            if($file['name'] !==''){
                if($file['type']== 'application/pdf'){
                    return true;
                }else{
                   return false;
                }
            }else{
            return true;
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule :

'required' => false,